# Set user role in Google Analytics with gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm trying to set some user properties in my Google Analytics 4.

I'm setting the logged in user in my application by running these two commands:

```
    gtag('config', MEASUREMENT_ID, {
      user_id: String(user?.id),
    });

    gtag('set', 'user_properties', {
      role: String(user?.roles[0].key),
      role_name: String(user?.roles[0].name),
    });

    gtag('send', 'user_properties');
```

Then I created a Custom dimension in the Events tab for the User role. When I was creating it, the `role` property was available and I was able to create that and have this in the Custom dimensions list. Now, I'm trying to use this dimension as filter in the Engagement -> Events, which shows up there but it displays this tooltip saying that there is no data available:

[image]

I suspected that the user_properties data have not been sent, then I tried `gtag('send', 'pageview');` but it stills shows this tooltip.

What am I missing? thanks in advance